# VBA ByRef argument type mismatch passing varaint array between subs

Tags: arrays, vba, compiler-errors

I have code which reads data from one workbook and uses them in another. I put the data into a 4D Variant Array. It gets passed around between subs using ByRef. When I come to access an element I get

> Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

If I add importArray to Watchlist in the context of `OneIterationOfTask()` and then break the code the variant array is still populated with data. How can I get a value out of a specific index e.g. `importArray(1,2,3,4)`?

```
'Called when user clicks button - Variant Array okay here
Public Sub WriteValues()
   Dim importArray() As Variant

   importArray = getImportArray()

   useImportArray importArray 
End Sub

'Gets values from another workbook - Variant Array okay here
Private Function getImportArray() As Variant
   Dim importArray() As Variant ' 4D array of strings stored as variants
   
   [...Get data...]

   getImportArray = importArray' Return array
End Sub

'Decides how to use import array - Variant Array okay here
Private Sub useImportArray (ByRef importArray())
   oneIterationOfTask importArray
End Sub 

'Repetitive code  - Variant Array ByRef argument type mismatch. 
Private Sub OneIterationOfTask (ByRef importArray())
   WriteStringOutput importArray(1,2,3,4) 'Okay if I comment out this line
End Sub
```

Comment: Typed arrays are a mess... even when they're *implicitly* typed like here. I'd recommend just passing them around as plain `Variant` parameters, e.g. `ByRef imports As Variant`; `getImportArray` is returning a plain `Variant`.

Comment: Try assigning `importArray(1, 2, 3, 4)` to a string variable, and then passing the string variable to `WriteStringOutput`.

Comment: @Domenic - you were very close with that. It was not the array that was the problem, but putting CStr() around any strings stored as Variants used when Strings were expected.

Comment: That's great, glad it's sorted out, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem it turns out was not with Variant arrays, despite appearances. I tried using importArray(1,2,3,4) like a String, which is okay for my debugging lines like

```
MsgBox importArray(0, 0, 1, 0) 'Test accessing array
```

This was not okay for other calls, though.

The problem was solved by using CStr(importArray(0, 0, 1, 0)) to convert Variants to Strings, which I should have been doing anyway.